# How to use jQuery bind or addEventListener in arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, addeventlistener

I want to get value of checked radio input on every blur or click or focus event of radio inputs.

```
function getCheckedVal(){
    var checked = $('#education_number input:radio:checked')
    console.log(checked.val());
};
```

This is not works:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var radio = $('#education_number input:radio');
    for(var i=0; i<radio.length; i++){
        radio[i].addEventListener('blur', function(){getCheckedVal()});
        };
    }
```

And this is raise an exception:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var radio = $('#education_number input:radio');
    for(var i=0; i<radio.length; i++){
        radio[i].bind('blur', getCheckedVal());
        };
    }
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #HTMLInputElement has no method 'bind'

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, you're *calling* `getCheckedVal` and then passing its return value into `bind`. You don't want those `()` after `getCheckedVal`:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var radio = $('#education_number input:radio');
    for(var i=0; i<radio.length; i++){
        $(radio[i]).bind('blur', getCheckedVal);
    }
}
```

(Note I added `$(...)` around `radio[i]`, because `radio[i]` is a raw DOM element, not a jQuery object.)

But you can dramatically simplify that code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    $('#education_number input:radio').blur(getCheckedVal);
}
```

jQuery is very set-based. You can operate on the entire matched set of elements, rather than looping through the set yourself.

Two things to consider, though:

- Do you *really* only want this information on blur? Not on `change`, for instance?
- Do you really want to wait until the `window#load` event to hook up your event handlers? That's **very** late in the page load process, after all of your images and such have *finished* loading. Rather than using `window#load`, consider either putting your script at the end, just before the closing `</body>` tag, or using jQuery's [`ready` function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 0):

`bind` is a jQuery method, but all you've got at this stage is an `HTMLInputElement` - luckily, you can pass an element to jQuery and get access to all of its functionality:

Change:

```
radio[i].bind('blur', getCheckedVal());
```

to

```
$(radio[i]).bind('blur', getCheckedVal);
```

You also need to remove the parentheses from `getCheckedVal` - passing getCheckedVal() to `bind` will cause the function to be evaluated immediately and only the return value will be bound to your event.  Instead, you need to pass the function reference to `bind`.

Answer (score 0):

It is just:

```
$('#education_number input:radio').bind('blur', getCheckedVal);
```

Note the missing `()` after `getCheckedVal`. You have to pass a *reference* to the function, not *call* the function.

I recommend to read one of the [jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials), to learn about the basics.

One big advantage of jQuery is that it lets you easily perform actions on a collection of HTML elements. `$('selector')` always returns a jQuery object so you can take advantage of that. If you had a pure array of DOM elements, then yes, you'd have to iterate over them and bind the event handler individually.